# Why does my parallel projection appear inverted?

Tags: c, math, matrix, projection

I have the following parallel projection (Row major):

[image]

Before I apply the projection I use the following matrix to apply a transformation on the original points:

**EDIT correct MATRIX:**[Matrix](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=%7B%7B1%2C0%2C0%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C1%2C0%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2Cs%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C0%2C1%7D%7D%7B%7Bcos%5C%2840%29a%5C%2841%29%2C-sin%5C%2840%29a%5C%2841%29%2C0%2C0%7D%2C%7Bsin%5C%2840%29a%5C%2841%29%2Ccos%5C%2840%29a%5C%2841%29%2C0%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C1%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C0%2C1%7D%7D%7B%7Bcos%5C%2840%29b%5C%2841%29%2C0%2Csin%5C%2840%29b%5C%2841%29%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C1%2C0%2C0%7D%2C%7B-sin%5C%2840%29b%5C%2841%29%2C0%2Ccos%5C%2840%29b%5C%2841%29%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C0%2C1%7D%7D%7B%7B1%2C0%2C0%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2Ccos%5C%2840%29g%5C%2841%29%2C-sin%5C%2840%29g%5C%2841%29%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2Csin%5C%2840%29g%5C%2841%29%2Ccos%5C%2840%29g%5C%2841%29%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C0%2C1%7D%7D)

Where `a` is `z` rotation,`b` is `y` rotation and `g` is `x` rotation and `s` scales my wireframe height.

And it is giving me the following output:

[image]

When in reality it should be giving me this (image not centered):

[image]

n is 0.1
and f is 100
The origin is in the middle of the wireframe and the 42 wireframe height is in the +z direction.

My matrix multiplication:

```
typedef struct s_point
{
    float   x;
    float   y;
    float   z;
    int     c; //color
}   t_point;


void    multiply_matrix_vector(t_point *i, t_point *o, t_pmatrix *m)
{
    float   w;

    o->x = i->x * m->m[0][0] + i->y * m->m[1][0] + i->z * m->m[2][0] + m->m[3][0];
    o->y = i->x * m->m[0][1] + i->y * m->m[1][1] + i->z * m->m[2][1] + m->m[3][1];
    o->z = i->x * m->m[0][2] + i->y * m->m[1][2] + i->z * m->m[2][2] + m->m[3][2];
    w = i->x * m->m[0][3] + i->y * m->m[1][3] + i->z * m->m[2][3] + m->m[3][3];
    if (w != 0.0f)
    {
        o->x /= w;
        o->y /= w;
        o->z /= w;
    }
    o->c = i->c;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I remembered that I was having a hard time with matrix multiplication before and that probably I might had screwed a sign or a trigonometric function. I double checked everything and but all was ok. Still the result was flipped on the y axis so what I did was this:

[Matrix](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=%7B%7B1%2C0%2C0%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C-1%2C0%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2Cs%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C0%2C1%7D%7D%7B%7Bcos%5C%2840%29a%5C%2841%29%2C-sin%5C%2840%29a%5C%2841%29%2C0%2C0%7D%2C%7Bsin%5C%2840%29a%5C%2841%29%2Ccos%5C%2840%29a%5C%2841%29%2C0%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C1%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C0%2C1%7D%7D%7B%7Bcos%5C%2840%29b%5C%2841%29%2C0%2Csin%5C%2840%29b%5C%2841%29%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C1%2C0%2C0%7D%2C%7B-sin%5C%2840%29b%5C%2841%29%2C0%2Ccos%5C%2840%29b%5C%2841%29%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C0%2C1%7D%7D%7B%7B1%2C0%2C0%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2Ccos%5C%2840%29g%5C%2841%29%2C-sin%5C%2840%29g%5C%2841%29%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2Csin%5C%2840%29g%5C%2841%29%2Ccos%5C%2840%29g%5C%2841%29%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C0%2C1%7D%7D)

On the first matrix at `[1][1]` I just changed the `1` for `-1`

Matrices are tricky because the multiplication order matters more than one would think

Comment: Just curious, was this what Irelia was suggesting [or an equivalent] of? For completeness of your question, maybe you can edit your answer here to show the changes to your function.

Comment: @CraigEstey Sure I'll edit it. just to be clear I didn't understand what Irelia was asking